# interacting with a already opened and visible webpage with Ruby

Tags: ruby, automation, screen-scraping, web-scraping, interactive

I know of gems like Mechanize which let you open a website, give credentials and eg scrape the contents. I also know of AutoIt and its use through Ruby to interact with already opened windows but i wonder if there is something better and more Ruby-like like Mechanize but for an already opened and visible site, it would simplify the logon procedure which for some sites isn't easy to do in the gems i know of. I intend to use it for semi-automating frequent tasks with sites that are difficult to log on to with a bot and also to have more visual interaction. I tried it with Sikuli but although promising it isn't reliable yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for Watir. It automates a browser from ruby.

Comment: can you publish or point to an example which shows the use i desire in my question ?

Comment: b = Watir::Browser.new;
b.goto 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'

in what way this interacts with a ALLREADY OPEN website ?

Comment: There's an attach method that connects to an open browser. I'm not here to do your work for you, just pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript and jquery by injecting jquery into the page and writing little custom login scripts for each of these frequent sites you visit that are "already open in the browser"

Then store the javascript bookmarks in your favorites.

Textmate has a nice addon for converting javascript to a bookmarklet.  Test in the console then convert it and use as bookmark.

Comment: then i would use greasemonkey, but i search a Ruby solution